# How to change the background color for a Form in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I wanna change that "light gray" background color for a form, but `.foregroundColor(Color.blue)` and `.background(Color.blue)` does not seem to work

```
struct ContentView : View {

 @State var value = ""

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("First Name")) {
                TextField($value)
            }
            Section(header: Text("Last Name")) {
                TextField($value)
            }
        }.foregroundColor(Color.blue)

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You probably need to post more code, because something as basic as a `background` modifier feels like it's not your issue. Is this a modal popup? Are you working with a `ZStack`? Please, give us more details, or accept the answer given by @Quinn. Let us duplicate the issue.

Comment: @dfd That's the only view I have, a form with 2 fields (it's meant to be a registration form), I'll probably add a button, but there isn't any popup or ZStack. I already tried `.background(Color.blue)` on Form, but it does not work. I guess Form is a special view or maybe it's just a bug and someone found an workaround

Comment: Found it. I'll post an answer, and if you need some tweaking, let me know.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

## iOS 16

You can hide the default background to show the underling view by appealing the following modifier to the `Form`:

```
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
```

---

## iOS 13 and 15

All SwiftUI's `List`s are backed by a `UITableView`in iOS. so you need to change the background color of *the tableView*. But since `Color` and `UIColor` values are slightly different, you can get rid of the `UIColor`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    init(){
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    @State var value = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("First Name")) {
                TextField("First Name", text: $value)
            }
            Section(header: Text("Last Name")) {
                TextField("Last Name", text: $value)
            }
        }
      /*.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)*/ //  this line will work only on iOS 16 and above 
        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
        .background(Color.yellow)
    }
}
```

Now you can use **Any background** (including all `Color`s) you want

[image: Preview]

**Note that** those top and bottom white areas are *safe are* and you can use `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea()` modifier to get rid of them.

---

## Restore

Since `UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor` applies globally, you can use `.onAppear` modifier to change it in different views (since it is a global change). So you can use **another** `onAppear` or `onDisappear` to *reset it* back to what you want.

And the default colors are:

`UIColor.systemGroupedBackground` for the **grouped style**. And

`UIColor.systemBackground` for the **plain style**.

And they both have automatic support for both dark mode and light mode.

Comment: `UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear` changes the style universally, which is not an ideal solution. But, there is no alternative solution that I could find.

Comment: you can use `.onAppear()` modifier to make it act like it is just for that page. ;) @WilliamGrand

Comment: Hmm, my experience on Xcode 11.6 and Xcode 12 beta 4 is that `.onAppear()` applies universally.

Comment: Of course you should use **another** `onAppear` or `onDisappear` to *reset it* back to what you want ;) @WilliamGrand

Comment: How can I reset it? I mean want to change Form default background color

Comment: @KenanNur just set `UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor` to any color you want in `.onDisappear`

Comment: I know but I want to change it default value. How can I know default Form background RGB code?

Comment: `UIColor.systemGroupedBackground` for the grouped style and `UIColor.systemBackground` for the plain

Comment: This is no longer correct for iOS 14. UITableView no longer backs Lists.

Comment: It works for me on iOS 15

Answer (score 19):

## For all versions

After seeing these solutions I created a modifier for you use when in iOS 16 and below.

```
struct FormHiddenBackground: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            content.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        } else {
            content.onAppear {
                UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
            }
            .onDisappear {
                UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .systemGroupedBackground
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use it you just need to update after a form.

```
 Form {
     Text("Test text")
 }
 .frame(height: 400)
 .modifier(FormHiddenBackground())
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the only solution that works on iOS16 with Xcode 14.2

Answer (score 9):

try this

```
.onAppear {
   UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .blue
}
```

Comment: `UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .blue` changes the style universally, which is not an ideal solution. But, there is no alternative solution that I could find.

Comment: for anyone who doesn't want to change it universally, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69237111/3408316)

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer by Mojtaba Hosseini, above, works but the init() statement is not a good place for the `UITableView` statement.  This is because it "hard codes" the ContentView's init parameters.  In this case it has none so everything works but if an `@ObservedObject` was added to the view then this would break the init function.

Much simpler just to add the UITable statement to the `body`, explicitly return the `Form` and delete the `init()`.

```
var body: some View {
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    return Form {...}
 }
```

However, setting the background colour on the `Form` usually works as expected.  The fact that it is not working on the `ContentView` screen may be a bug.

Comment: Error: Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

Answer (score 7):

#### Don't change the global `appearance()`.

You can use `UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .red` for example to set the `Form`'s background color to red. This can go in the `init` of the view, however this affects *every* `List` and `Form`.

Alternatively, you could use [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) to customise a single one by doing something like:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var value = ""

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("First Name")) {
                TextField("First", text: $value)
            }

            Section(header: Text("Last Name")) {
                TextField("Last", text: $value)
            }
        }
        .introspectTableView { $0.backgroundColor = .systemBlue }
        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

[image: Result]

You can also add the following to each section to make the sections blue too:

```
.listRowBackground(Color.blue)
```

Comment: No longer works in iOS 16 as form views are now backed by collection views, not table views. Illustrates the danger of assuming the underlying implementation will always be the same.

Answer (score 4):

In **iOS 17**, You can change background color of `Form` using combination of

```
.background(Color.yellow)
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
```

applying them on Form modifiers.

```
Form {
  ...
}
.background(Color.yellow)
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to modify safe area  of the `Form`, you can use `ZStack`as well:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    init(){
        
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    @State var value = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(UIColor.systemYellow)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("First Name")) {
                    TextField("First Name", text: $value)
                }
                Section(header: Text("Last Name")) {
                    TextField("Last Name", text: $value)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy these codes below each of your *Form* view:

```
Form {
    // Your form view 
} 
.onAppear { // ADD THESE AFTER YOUR FORM VIEW
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear 
}
.onDisappear { // CHANGE BACK TO SYSTEM's DEFAULT
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .systemGroupedBackground 
} 
.background(.yellow) // Add your background color
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions above didn't really work for what I was trying to achieve. I wanted an initial screen with a clear background for the form, and subsequent screens to have the default iOS systemGroupedBackground color. Using appear() and disappear() didn't work for me as switching between various tabs was leading to bugs in the appearance.

I came up with the following solution. It borrows from the solutions above.

For my ContentView screen, I inserted this code just inside the Struct.

```
init(){
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
}
```

This is a global change that affects all forms.

For all forms where I wanted the default color to work, I inserted this code just outside the Form {}.

```
.background(Color(.systemGroupedBackground))
```

Answer (score -2):

To make it universal for all iOS versions, you can create an extension for View.

```
extension View {

    @ViewBuilder
    func hideFormBackground() -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        } else {
            introspectTableView {
                $0.backgroundColor = .clear
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then, when you declaring your form, use it:

```
Form {
    SomeContent
}
.hideFormBackground()
```

Comment: This requires Introspect and is not a suitable solution.