# Is it possible to add a shadow in a Form in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to build a UI that consist of buttons (which act as Links) inside a Settings Screen using SwiftUI's Form. In order to make this UI, I already used [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58427664/13811694) which allows me to change the UITableView color from gray (default when creating a Form) to white. The only thing missing is a shadow modifier that highlight my buttons.

I already tried to add a Rectangle with a shadow but that only broke the Form.
And if I try to add a shadow modifier to my SettingCell it only throws it on the letters and not underneath the rounded rectangle.

Thanks for the help.

[image: UI]

Comment: Not really. `Form` is one of those Views that are take it or leave it.

Comment: Thank you. So the best option would be to just build the actions as Buttons and then  add a link to them?