# How to change the background color of a form?

Tags: forms, swiftui, background-color, swiftui-form

I'm not able to change the background color of a Form in SwiftUI for iOS < 16. It always takes default form backgroundcolor depending on which color scheme is selected in the iPhone settings. All solution I found here to set the UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear also don't work. Do any of you have a solution?

I tried different solutions:

- UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
- ```
  GeometryReader { geometry in
              ZStack {
                  Rectangle().foregroundColor(.white).frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                  Form {
                      // your form content here
                  }
              }
          }
  ```
- ```
  struct FormBackgroundColorModifier: ViewModifier {
      var color: Color

      func body(content: Content) -> some View {
          ZStack {
              color.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
              content
          }
      }
  }

  struct MyForm: View {
      var body: some View {
          Form {

          }
          .modifier(FormBackgroundColorModifier(color: .white))
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57254461/how-to-change-the-background-color-for-a-form-in-swiftui

Answer (score 4):

Just use `.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text("A")
            Text("B")
            Text("C")
        }
        .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        .background(.red)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes thats working but unfortunately only for iOS 16 and above :(